# Pro Rata holiday formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to work out pro rata holiday using a start date, how do I do this?  I have one column with the name and the column next to it with their start date.  They are allowed 20 days pro rata holiday, but I need to work out what they are entitled to from their start date.

So for instance, if they started in September they wouldn't be entitled to the same amount of holiday as someone who started in January.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation would be (would need rounding):

```
=Total_Holiday_Allowance - (Total_Holiday_Allowance/365)*Start_Date_Number
```

where `Start_Date_Number` is the day number in the year.

So with a holiday allowance of 20 days and a start date of today:

```
=20-(20/365)*DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("1 January 2018"),TODAY(),"d")
```

This would give 3.068493 days holiday remaining (6th November) - round up or down is your choice.

Using cell references:

```
=$B$1-($B$1/365)*DATEDIF($A$1,$B4,"d")
```

Where `B1` is the holiday allowance, `A1` is the start of the year date and `B4` is the employee start date.
You may need to change 365 to account for leap years.